# Using MVC, I am trying to update a 'score' variable for a Users profile when they complete a quiz in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Currently I have a controller that contains some quiz questions and for each answer the user gets correct I have a score variable that updates it. When the quiz is finished I am trying to  make it that the local score variable is then be added to a score variable I have in the user profile class.

Here is the httppost

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ifStatement(Evaluation model, UserProfile model2)
    {
        int score;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var q in model.Questions)
            {
                var qId = q.ID;


                List<string> listSelectedAnswer = new List<string>();

                listSelectedAnswer.Add("14");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("19");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("22");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("25");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("28");
                listSelectedAnswer.Add("33");



                score = 0;

                foreach (string answer in listSelectedAnswer)
                {
                    foreach (var answer2 in model.Questions)
                    {
                        if (answer == answer2.SelectedAnswer)
                        {
                            // return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
                            score = score + 12;
                        }
                        // return Content("score hit");


                    }
                }

                score = model2.Score;
                if (score > 30)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("ThankYou");
                }



                else
                {
                    //score = 0;
                    //return Content("Please check all answers have been submitted!");
                    return RedirectToAction("ThankYou"); //PRG Pattern
                }



            }
        }
```

So this is the user profile class which stores the score variable attached to that user. The goal here is to add the score they get in the quiz to their user profile score..

```
 [Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int Score;
  //  public Leaderboard leaderboard { get; set; }
}
```

This is the view though it only begins the quiz form.

```
    @model JavaTutorial.Models.Evaluation

    <h2>Quiz 24</h2>


<p>The following section is the Quiz for IF Statements</p>


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Here is the question answer and evaluation class. Evaluation contains a score integer.

```
    public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string QuestionText { set; get; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { set; get; }
    [Required]

    public string SelectedAnswer { set; get; }

    public Question()
    {
        Answers = new List<Answer>();
    }
}
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public int SelectedID { set; get; }
    public string AnswerText { set; get; }

}
public class Evaluation
{
    public List<UserProfile> UserProfile;
    public int Score;
    public List<Question> Questions { set; get; }
    public Evaluation()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }
    public Evaluation()
    {
        UserProfile = new List<UserProfile>();
    }
}
```

After all this I want it to add to a leaderboard. The leaderboard takes in the users name and their current up to date score. At the moment it shows their name but has the score at 0..

This is the leaderboard view then which takes the score though its still 0..

```
    @model IEnumerable<JavaTutorial.Models.UserProfile>

<h2>Leaderboard</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            UserId
        </th>

        <th>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;UserName
        </th>
        <th>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Score
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

    <tr>
        <td>
             &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
        </td>
         <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
        </td>
       <td>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Score)
        </td>

    </tr>

}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right before you check the local score value is greater than 30 you assign it the value from the user profile score. So if I scored 20 on the quiz, it would get reset to 0 by my profile, if my total score was still 0.

Unless I am missing something, it looks like you calculate the local score, then rather than add that to their score you replace it with their score, which is probably still 0 since it can never get added to their profile.